# System time problems on Debian (wait for clock tick timed out)

Tags: debian, time

I just installed a new server and changed the time zone by using the command:

```
dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

the system clock is correct now but `/sbin/hwclock --systohc` doesn't work:

```
select() to /dev/rtc to wait for clock tick timed out
```

date command, for example, `date -s 14:30` works fine.

Any ideas how to fix it in an easy way?

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug with older versions of Debian. You can either upgrade or pass `--directisa` to every invocation of `hwclock`.

Comment: Older versions? I have Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.5 (squeeze) I think it's not old. Can you please show an example how to use --directisa? Thanks.

Comment: Try 'man hwclock' for how to use --directisa.

Comment: Do you perhaps have really old BIOS then?

Comment: BIOS Information Vendor: FUJITSU // American Megatrends Inc.Version: V4.6.5.1 R1.5.0 for D3090-A1x  Release Date: 02/03/2012. I think that before I changed the time zone hwclock worked fine. But I am not 100% sure.